# Unable to fetch cookie on different domains in reactjs expressjs

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, cors, cross-domain

Title: Unable to receive cookies from backend on different domains

Description:

I'm working on a web application where I need to send a cookie from the backend when a user logs in. Initially, everything was working fine when I was testing it locally on localhost:3000. However, when I tried accessing the application from a network URL (192.168.1.2:3000), I was unable to receive the cookie. I also deployed the application on Render, but the issue persisted.

Here's the relevant code:

Backend Code(loginUser endpoint):

```
export const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Code to validate user credentials...

        // Generate JWT token
        const token = user.getJWTToken();

        const options = {
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRE * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
            httpOnly: true,
            domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === "DEVELOPMENT" ? ".localhost" : process.env.SUBDOMAIN
        };

        res.status(200).cookie("token", token, options).json({ success: true, user, token });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
    }
};
```

Frontend Code(login action):

```
export const login = (userData) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_REQUEST });

        const config = {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        };

        const { data } = await loginUser(userData, config);
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
         });
     } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL,
        payload: error.response.data.message
    });
  }
```

};

Additional Information:

I have set the process.env.SUBDOMAIN variable to ".onrender.com".
In my API request, I'm using axios to send the request.
In my index.js file, I have set the default base URL and enabled sending cookies with requests using `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;.`
I suspect the issue is related to cross - domain requests.I need the cookies to work on every platform.Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.